# Location Point Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

I registered a location point to use it in whatasapp but it has been done for about 15 days and it does not stop so I can check in.
The name of the location point is "PB Consult, Cabedelo, Paraíba, Brazil

Comment: What is your question, can you post a screenshot for make it more clearer to understand. Thank you

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow ! Could you provide us with more details on your actual question ?

Comment: Registei-me um ponto local chamado "PB Consulte" no Foursquare, mas ele não aparece para o check-in no whats app